# Wrong table used when running tests Django Pycharm

Tags: python, mysql, django, pycharm, mysql-connector-python

I used inspectdb to import the Models schema from MySQL database connected with MySQL Connector/Python.

When I run the tests, the system shows:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Table 'test_mydb.cards' doesn't exist
```

But the table name is just `mydb.cards`, not `test_mydb.cards`

Why is this prefix being added? My app's name is just `container`.

Comment: When you run `manage.py test`, it creates a brand-new database (by prepending `test_` to the db name) to make sure the tests don't muck with your real data.  But that doesn't explain why Django isn't creating the correct table.

Comment: Is there a way to force Django to use the same DB? I have set the whole schema to read-only in MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason: I had `managed` property to `False` in `models.py Class Meta` for each table. I never set it there myself, it is the default after doing `inspectdb`.

Please read: [Django Models Options: Managed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#managed)

Answer (score 0):

Django uses [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#module-unittest) module for testing, also it creates a blank database for testing as tests should be run ideally always on same blank database or fixtures filled database.

> [Tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/overview/) that require a database (namely, model tests) will not use your
>   “real” (production) database. Separate, blank databases are created
>   for the tests.
>
> Regardless of whether the tests pass or fail, the test databases are
>   destroyed when all the tests have been executed.

Check out if you are having migration sorted for the table test tries to access, as all tables that don't have migrations aren't accessible to test suite without monkeypatching or workarounds